# Outlook rule to stop 'leaking' e-mails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've got this Outlook rule set to forward all e-mails from my department to a folder aptly called "IT". It's only like 4 names plus the IT account. Problem is, messages that having nothing to do with IT also go in there, because it's from one of the users in the rule.

I want to set it so that only the e-mails going *to* the IT department *from* the IT department go to that e-mail folder.

For example, my boss is arguing with another department's boss over e-mail. The other department's boss' e-mails stay in my inbox, while my boss' reply go to my IT folder. 
Even though this chain of e-mails has nothing to do with IT. I know that it only goes to the IT folder because of the rule 'E-mails sent from {boss' e-mail account} go to folder "IT"'.

Anyone know how I can set it so that only e-mails coming *from* the IT department *to* the IT department go to my IT folder? Sorry if my explanation is lousy, I'll provide clarification if needed.

Comment: What do you mean about redirecting messages addressed to the IT department?  That part doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I never mentioned redirecting. Incoming e-mails from the IT department are put to a folder called "IT". Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Your examples are somewhat helpful. What would help more is if you have examples of the IT account e-mail and the 4 other e-mails you reference in your first paragraph.

Comment: @Sun Thanks, appreciate the feedback. The other 4 e-mails are the rest of the people in the department, but aren't the generic IT e-mail, e.g. Paul@company.com, John@company.com, IT@company.com. Only e-mails coming FROM these people and only TO these people (including myself) will go to the IT folder. E-mails with other participants will go to the normal inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule needs to look at the TO and FROM within one rule. You also need to look at order in which rules are processed. You have to option of "stop processing more rules". If you want one rule to process first, place that rule up top before the other and check on "stop processing more rules".